# rviz Error - Global Status: Fixed frame [map] does not exist

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, p3at

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I loaded a map in rviz using the map_server. I made the pgm file of map using p3at robot in Gazebo.
The map is loaded but showing error:

The error is : **Fixed frame [map] does not exist**.

I am not able to spawn the robot in rviz again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226298/rviz-error---global-status:-fixed-frame-%5Bmap%5D-does-not-exist/) by [Arpit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23890/arpit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-03-26**:
You can explore the problem by setting up one or more static tf as in https://answers.ros.org/question/221329/rviz-fixed-frame-map-does-not-exist/?answer=286624#post-id-286624 ,  to fulfil the `map->base_link` tf relationship described by **mig** , above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't have a localization as e.g. [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) running.
Thus, the transformation `map->base_link` (or whatever you have for your robots link) does not exist.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arpit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23890/arpit/) on 2016-02-13**:
amcl is running but timeout is occurring at obtaining the transformation map->base_link !

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-02-15**:
the above answer is all you'll get without providing more information.

We need the launch files, configurations, the output of `rosrun tf view_frames`.
Ideally, send a link to GitHub where you have your files...